# HTTP 500 error while open http://localhost:8080/geoserver/web in windows 10

Tags: geoserver, installation, windows-10

Im just now installed the GeoServer in my system . The installation process fine.After the installation i have started the GeoServer then i tried to use **geo server web admin page** but it is showing some error.in google chrome **This is a proxy server. Does not respond to non-proxy requests.**

And the internet explorer shows that

**HTTP 500 error

That’s odd... Microsoft Edge can’t find this page

This page can’t be displayed, because this site’s server might be under maintenance or there could be a programming error.
**

I have uninstalled the GeoServer and the i change the port 8080  to 8085 then also not working well. this time the error is changed ie, **dial tcp [::1]:8085: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.**

Comment: @PolyGeo do you have any suggestion for this issue?

Comment: I am not a potential answerer of your question.

Comment: Please edit the question to discuss what steps you have taken to be assured that the "actively refused" connection wasn't due to a misconfigured firewall.

Comment: I got solution for this.  in my system the port 8085 is already used by some   process and what i did , i just changed the port no for Geo server to 8081 the its works form me. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this. In my system, port 8085 is already used by some process. Therefore, I just changed the port number for GeoServer to 8081 and it works.